# How to change cell name in PHPEXCEL

Tags: php

> How to change set custom cell name in excel Example:cell name A1 to
>   "ID"

Answer (score -1):

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
```